# Filling hash by reference in a procedure

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I'm trying to call a procedure, which is filling a hash by reference. The reference to the hash is given as a parameter. The procedure fills the hash, but when I return, the hash is empty. Please see the code below.
What is wrong?

```
$hash_ref;
genHash ($hash_ref);
#hash is empty


sub genHash {
    my ($hash_ref)=(@_);
    #cut details; filling hash in a loop like this:
    $hash_ref->{$lid} = $sid;
    #hash is generetad , filled and i can dump it
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to initialize hashref first,

```
my $hash_ref = {};
```

as autovivification happens inside function to another lexical variable.

(Not so good) alternative is to use scalars inside `@_` array which are directly aliased to original variables,

```
$_[0]{$lid} = $sid;
```

And btw, consider `use strict; use warnings;` to all your scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I usually/always use `use strict; use warnings;` but cutted them for simplification .

Answer (score 2):

The caller's `$hash_ref` is undefined. The `$hash_ref` in the sub is therefore undefined too. `$hash_ref->{$lid} = $sid;` autovivifies the sub's `$hash_ref`, but nothing assigns that hash reference to the caller's `$hash_ref`.

**Solution 1**: Actually passing in a hash ref to assign to the caller's `$hash_ref`.

```
sub genHash {
    my ($hash_ref) = @_;
    ...
}

my $hash_ref = {};
genHash($hash_ref);
```

**Solution 2**: Taking advantage of the fact that Perl passes by reference.

```
sub genHash {
    my $hash_ref = $_[0] ||= {};
    ...
}

my $hash_ref;
genHash($hash_ref);
   -or-
genHash(my $hash_ref);
```

**Solution 3**: If the hash is going to be empty initially, why not just create it in the sub?

```
sub genHash {
    my %hash;
    ...
    return \%hash;
}

my $hash_ref = genHash();
```